# VBA: Filtering and deleting contents in column

Tags: vba, excel, filtering

Sorry for the simple question, still pretty new to VBA.

I have a spreadsheet with columns A-Z populated. What I want to do is to filter column C (contains employee ID) based on a few employees, and then delete only the contents in column Q (which contains employee hours worked), deleting only the visible contents.

To be clearer, I would filter column C based on some criteria, then go to column Z. In column Z I would like to delete only the contents in column Z (not the entire row), based on the visible rows. So essentially after filtering I'd like to delete all the visible contents in column Z. The number of rows for the spreadsheet is always growing, so I can't use what I'm using right now which is just selecting specific cells and deleting the contents. Hopefully that makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you could accomplish this by filtering and then clearing visible cells, iterating over employee ids and checking their value is a bit more straightforward. This will also continue to work even if the number of rows in your spreadsheet grows, provided the values in column C are continuous.

```
Sub ClearCells()
     Dim employeeId As Range
     Dim deleteIds As Variant
     deleteIds = Array(14, 35, 17) ' Put your employee ids in here
     For Each employeeId In Range(ActiveSheet.Range("C1"), ActiveSheet.Range("C1").End(xlDown))
        If Not (IsError(Application.Match(employeeId.Value, deleteIds, 0))) Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("Z" & employeeId.Row).Value = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```